# Send data via POST to API and show response in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl, post

I have a little problem, I am somewhat new to PHP and I can't get something to work.

I will explain.

I have access to a shipping API (Parcel), it gives me the possibility to track the packages by means of a guide number or a shipping ID and it returns the response in JSON with the status of the shipment.

I have made a small script that performs the tracing functions but I can't get it to show me neither the "main" status nor the "sub-events".

The request is sent via POST and the response looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "enviaya_shipment_number": "N9T30TAC",
    "carrier_tracking_number": "9878401142",
    "channel": "Api",
    "estimated_delivery_date": null,
    "expected_delivery_date": "12/01/2022",
    "pickup_date": "2021-12-30T10:39:11-06:00",
    "shipment_status": "En tránsito",
    "event_code": 151,
    "event_description": "Llegada al Centro de DHL",
    "event": "Llegada",
    "status_code": 14,
    "sub_event_code": null,
    "sub_event": null,
    "sub_event_description": null,
    "checkpoints": [
        {
            "code": "PU",
            "description": "Envío recibido",
            "date": "2022-01-03T12:12:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "PL",
            "description": "Procesado",
            "date": "2022-01-03T14:07:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "DF",
            "description": "Salida",
            "date": "2022-01-03T14:08:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "AF",
            "description": "Llegada",
            "date": "2022-01-03T15:30:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY HUB-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "PL",
            "description": "Procesado",
            "date": "2022-01-03T18:55:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY HUB-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "DF",
            "description": "Salida",
            "date": "2022-01-03T19:04:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY HUB-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "AF",
            "description": "Llegada",
            "date": "2022-01-03T20:55:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "QUERETARO-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "PL",
            "description": "Procesado",
            "date": "2022-01-03T22:03:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "QUERETARO-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "DF",
            "description": "Salida",
            "date": "2022-01-03T22:31:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "QUERETARO-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "AR",
            "description": "Llegada",
            "date": "2022-01-04T01:52:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MERIDA-MEX"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I made a form in HTML for the client to send the data, it is something very simple:

```
<form action="track.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form-app">
<fieldset class="row">

<!-- Heading -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h3 class="legend">Rastreo de Paquetes</h3>
</div>


<!-- Select List -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group required-control">
        <label  class="control-label" for="carrier">Paquetería</label>
        <select id="carrier" name="carrier" data-alias=""  class="form-control" required  >
            <option value="UPS" >UPS</option>
            <option value="Redpack" >Redpack</option>
            <option value="Estafeta" >Estafeta</option>
            <option value="DHL" >DHL</option>
            <option value="99 Minutos" >99 Minutos</option>
            <option value="FedEx" >FedEx</option>
            <option value="iVoy" >iVoy</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Number -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group required-control">
        <label  class="control-label" for="number">Número de guía o ID de Envío</label>
        <input type="text" id="shipment" name="shipment" value="" data-alias="" data-integer-only="true"  class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-action">
        <button type="submit" id="button_1" name="button_1" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This in turn sends to the file that in theory connects with the API through cURL sending the data, receiving the response and decoding the JSON

```
<?php
include_once "key.php";
$shipment_number=$_POST["shipment"];
$carrier=$_POST["carrier"];

 //SEND REQUEST post TO api AND DECODE JSON RESPONSE
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/trackings");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "carrier=".$carrier."&shipment_number=".$shipment_number);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "api_key: ".$API_KEY
 ));
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $respuesta = json_decode($response);
 

//Show the response on HTML format with tables
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Estado del Envío</td><td>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Evento</td><td>".$respuesta->event_description."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Guía</td><td>".$respuesta->carrier_tracking_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>ID de Envio</td><td>".$respuesta->enviaya_shipment_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Fecha de envio</td><td>".$respuesta->pickup_date."</td></tr>";

//Show subevents on HTML format with tables
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Evento</td><td>Descripción</td><td>Fecha</td></tr>";
foreach ($respuesta->subevents as $subevent) {
  echo "<tr><td>".$subevent->event."</td><td>".$subevent->description."</td><td>".$subevent->date."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

However, something is obviously wrong since it shows me empty cells, that is, it does not show any data.

According to the `var_dump($respuesta);` The API key is incorrect but I already verified and it is fine.

Comment: If it the response says the API key is incorrect, that means either the API key is not correct or the way you are sending the API key in your request is incorrect. If you don't mind me asking, what is the API that you are using?

Comment: @Dula  The API is from "Envios Marva" Here is the documentation:
https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/docs/api#tracking

Answer (score 0):

Based on the shared code snippet, you were iterating through `subevent`. However,  I can't find any key called `subevent` in the response shared.

if `subevent` exist and it's in form of a list, then a foreach statement should work.

Kindly confirm where the `subevent` is coming from.

`foreach ($respuesta->subevents as $subevent)`

Comment: To be honest I am quite new and I think I do not apply it correctly, what I want is that each "checkpoint" shows it in a table

description, date and comments

But I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the answer:

First I passed the API key as a header and it had to be passed as one more parameter, and then I managed to make it show me the checkpoints in a table, the complete code is:

```
<?php
include_once "key.php";
$shipment_number=$_POST["shipment"];
$carrier=$_POST["carrier"];

$params = array(
  "api_key" => $API_KEY,
  "carrier" => $carrier,
  "shipment_number" => $shipment_number
);
$headers = array(
  "api_key=".$API_KEY
);
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/trackings",
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$respuesta = json_decode($response);
 

//Show the response on HTML format with tables
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Estado del Envío</td><td>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Evento</td><td>".$respuesta->event_description."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Guía</td><td>".$respuesta->carrier_tracking_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>ID de Envio</td><td>".$respuesta->enviaya_shipment_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Fecha de envio</td><td>".$respuesta->pickup_date."</td></tr>";

//Show checkpoints data in a table
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Checkpoint</td><td>Fecha</td><td>Código</td><td>Descripción</td><td>Ciudad</td><td>Estado</td><td>País</td><td>Comentarios</td></tr>";
foreach($respuesta->checkpoints as $checkpoint){
  echo "<tr><td>".$checkpoint->description."</td><td>".$checkpoint->date."</td><td>".$checkpoint->code."</td><td>".$checkpoint->description."</td><td>".$checkpoint->city."</td><td>".$checkpoint->state."</td><td>".$checkpoint->country."</td><td>".$checkpoint->comments."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```